# CoGroupByKey always failed on big data (PythonSDK)

Tags: debugging, google-cloud-dataflow, google-dataflow

I have about 4000 files (avg ~7MB each) input.

My pipeline always failed on the step CoGroupByKey when the data size reach about 4GB.
I tried to limit only use 300 file then it run just fine.

In case of fail, the logs on GCP dataflow only show:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: S24:CoGroup Geo data/GroupByKey/Read+CoGroup Geo data/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow+CoGroup Geo data/Map(_merge_tagged_vals_under_key) failed., The job failed because a work item has failed 4 times. Look in previous log entries for the cause of each one of the 4 failures. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors. The work item was attempted on these workers: 
  store-migration-10212040-aoi4-harness-m7j7
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.,
  store-migration-xxxxx
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.,
  store-migration-xxxxx
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.,
  store-migration-xxxxx
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.
```

I digging through all logs in Logs Explorer. Nothing else indicate error other than the above, even my `logging.info` and `try...except` code.

Think this relate to the memory of the instances but I didn't digging into that direction. Because it kindna what I don't want to worry about when I am using GCP services.

Thanks.

Comment: that's interesting! Thanks for sharing. `The worker lost contact with the service.` messages are common when the worker is suffering high pressure on memory. Can you share more details about your pipeline, and about the function coming after the CoGBK?

Comment: Agree with Pablo, it looks like a memory issue. Do you have hot keys? Have you tried machines with more memory?

Comment: @Pablo I tried  `n1-highmem-4` and `-8` and it still crashed. The GroupByKey within it said it have ~15GB mem data, which is less then `-8` and it still crash there.